# Audio in Unity WEBGL on IOS devices

Tags: ios, audio, unity-game-engine, unity-webgl

I have a problem getting my audioclips to play on ios devices in webgl. I have seen other games with audio working so i know it is possible. Now after 3 days of trying to fix the issue with no luck i really hope you can help me with the problem. I know a solution where you can add some meta tags and save it as a Webapp on your phone. But that is not the solution i am looking for.

Here is an example of a game where the audio works fine in an ios browser http://temple-run2.com/

Comment: That game you linked to is not made with Unity. As @Nick pointed out in his answer [Unity themselves say Unity in a browser is not supported on mobile devices](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/webgl-browsercompatibility.html).

Answer (score 0):

I quote:

*Note that Unity WebGL content is not currently supported on mobile devices. It may still work, especially on high-end devices, but many current devices are not powerful enough and don’t have enough memory to support Unity WebGL content well.*

[more info](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/webgl-browsercompatibility.html)

As so, uncontrolled behavior may (very likely) occur on mobile devices.

> I know a solution where you can add some meta tags and save it as a
>   Webapp on your phone.

What is wrong with just building to iOS nativly?

If you really need 3D content in a webbrowser that's supported on mobile devices, take a look at [threejs](https://threejs.org/)

Comment: We have to deliver the product soon to our costumer. it is already made in unity and a platform switch is not an option as its to time consuming. all is done and ready. It has no 3D elements. it is pure 2D curve animations, particles and audio. it works on all platforms.. except the audio in IOS browsers.

Comment: I don't see how switching from platform would be time consuming if it's a simple project. I did test the webgl on the latest iPad, iPad pro, iPad mini, iPhone 6 and a bunch of android devices, and there's always something else that's broken. I highly suggest you to do it correct, or the customer will end up with a product that doesn't even work half

Comment: However even Unity says that they don't support WebGL on mobiles, the project is yours. [Check this](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/webgl-interactingwithbrowserscripting.html)  You can add some external functions to play sounds externally rather than waiting Unity's sdk do it.